# PHPでサロゲートペア文字を含む文字列をPDF出力・CSV出力したい

Tags: cakephp, csv, pdf, 文字化け

CakePHP3でPDF出力とCSV出力がある機能を開発しており、
それぞれライブラリを使って実装しています。
(PDF出力はTCPDF+FPDIでフォントはIPAmj明朝、CSV出力はCsvViewでSJIS出力)
また、DBはMySQLで文字コードをutf8mb4にしてます。

通常の文字はもちろん、文字化けしそうな「髙」なども問題なく出力されるのですが、
「」(サロゲートペア文字)はPDF出力・CSV出力とも文字化けしてしまいます。
解消方法はありませんか？

Comment: サロゲートペアのうちSJISに存在しない文字についてはどのように表示されることを期待しているのか質問内容を明確にしてください。

Comment: PHPでの文字列は単なるバイト列ですので、「サロゲートペア」という概念はありません。「非BMP文字」などより正確な用語を使われた方が混乱を避けられるかと思います。SJISではUnicodeで定義された十数万の文字種のうち、わずか8千ほどしか表現できませんので非BMP文字に限らずBMP文字の範囲(UTF-8なら1〜3バイト)でも表現できない文字が山ほどあって、それらの文字に対して文字化けしないようにする方法はありません。選べるのは「どのように文字化けさせるか」だけです。(よくあるのが`?`になったり、U+FFFD(�)になったりするもの。)髙(U+9AD9)は厳密なSJISには含まれないのですが、Windows拡張文字に入っていたので、広義のSJISで表現できます。TCPDF+FPDIはよく知らないのですが、UTF-8対応でUnicodeベースのOpenTypeにも対応したフレームワークが(U+20BB7)のような単純な非BMP文字に対応できないことは考えにくいです。そちらはあなたのPHPコードに問題がある可能性が高そうです。コードをお示しください。